# How to access a huge map in Apache Spark?

Tags: memory, apache-spark, out-of-memory, bigdata, broadcast

I am calculating the skyline of a set of points where each point has a number of dimensions where each dimension has a double value. My input can be anything from thousands to millions of points with multiple dimensions. I am creating an algorithm where I have a huge map created as an RDD. The RDD looks like this:

`JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, BitSet> map`

Where the first int is the dimension, the second the ranking of a double in that dimension and BitSet is a bit representation of that value in that dimension. This map is smaller than the input but still can be very large (usually 10000+ elements) elements and I need to distribute it between all nodes. The first thing I did was a broadcast:

```
Broadcast<Map<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, BitSet>> broadcasted = sparkContext.broadcast(map.collectAsMap());
```

Which of course fails in Big Data because this map is way too memory consuming. This map needs to be accessed by every node in a read-only mode in order to perform some calculations, for example a node will do (with the broadcast):

```
BitSet bitSet = (BitSet) broadcasted.value().get(key).clone()

// perform calculations
```

This action will be done during a `map` or a `filter` action so I can't keep the map as an RDD and do `lookup`. Specifically, the second RDD that needs to access the map RDD looks like this:

`JavaPairRDD<Point, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> values;`

where the `Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>` is the list of keys that the `Point` needs during a 'filter' in order for me to see if the point is in the skyline or not.

```
JavaRDD<Point2D> skylines = pointsWithKeys
                .filter(p -> isSkyline(p._2()))
                .map(Tuple2::_1);
```

Inside `isSkyline` I need access to the map in order to access the bitsets depending on the keys I give it.

What is a more efficient way to distribute it between the nodes?

Comment: Could you add some info about amount of data as well? Number of records doesn't tell much.

Comment: @zero323 I added quite a bit in my edit now.

Comment: If adding more resources is not an option I would go with external storage. You didn't provide enough information about dataset size but some things you consider HDF5 / SQLite distributed to each node or globally accessible database could be an option.